# unable to resole: type object 'Member' has no attribute '_default_manager, django 1.10

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have the following problem:
When I am trying to delete a member from my DB via the template, I'm receiving the following error:

**type object 'Member' has no attribute '_default_manager**

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong, because everything seems to be as normal as possible. 
Bellow are my model, view and template  snippet for my issue.

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
)


class Member(models.Model):
    """Model for a member"""
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    names = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    dob = models.DateField()
    # anniversary = models.ForeignKey(Anniversary)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = PhoneNumberField(help_text='Please, use this format +3232')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    suburb = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=Suburbs_list, default=Suburbs_list[0][0])
    province = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=Provinces_List, default=Provinces_List[8][1])
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Unite Kingdom')
    previous_church = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    added_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.surname

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-suburb', 'province']
```

And my Delete View:

```
class DeleteMember(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DeleteView):
"""
This view will be responsible of deleting an member
"""
model = Member
template_name = 'members/delete_member.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('website:home')
```

and my form:

```
class MemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
dob = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget, label='Date of Birth')
phone = forms.CharField(label='Phone Number',
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '+41524242424'}))

class Meta:
    model = Member
    exclude = ['added_date']
    error_messages = {
        'phone': {
            'max_length': _("Please use this format +41524242424 ."),
            }
    }
```

and my Delete url:

```
url(r'^delete-member/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', DeleteMember.as_view(),
        name='delete_member'),
```

and in the template:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-edit" role="button" href="{% url "website:delete_member" pk=member.id %}">Delete</a>
```

And my traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /delete-member/1/delete/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 56, in dispatch
    return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 115, in get
    self.object = self.get_object()
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 32, in get_object
    queryset = self.get_queryset()
  File "/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 68, in get_queryset
    return self.model._default_manager.all()
AttributeError: type object 'Member' has no attribute '_default_manager'
```

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you share the traceback of you error ?

Comment: @Wilfried provided the traceback now

Comment: Maybe the problem comes from you [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin). You need to define some attribute like `login_url` and `redirect_field_name`. You can try without this mixin, to see if the problem comes from it

Comment: @ Wilfried even without mixin same problem

Comment: Maybe this seems to be obvious question, but are you sure that you correctly imported `Member` model?

Comment: @mateuszb yes I am, I have just 3 apps, website, members and visitors

Comment: from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView and just write DeleteView in your class based view `DeteleMember`, without generic. Don't know why you have `generic.`

Comment: @Wilfried but it still doesn't resolve my issue

Comment: I agree with @mateuszb - it looks like `Member` is not your `Member` model. You can add `print(Member)` to your views above the `DeleteMember` class to check what it is.

Answer (score 5):

I have found the issue, for some reason as I have called my model Member and my view Member as well, it was conflicted. So I just renamed the view.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Had the same issue on `Django==2.0.2`. Plumbed the depths of the internet to find this. Thanks cat

Comment: Had the same. I was importing my models like this: `.models import *` pycharm did not show any errors till i read this post. Thanks.

Comment: I had a class based view called "MyMenu" and another one called "Menu", I was working on the "MyMenu" view, but I got a 405 error. Today I read this post and I had a model called "Menu", so I changed the view with the name "Menu", and it worked.

Comment: This  worked for Django 4.1

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when django points to a different object apart from your model, so just check in serializers or signals or anything that you have imported in your views. You will find another object that has the same name as your model

Answer (score -1):

In my case the error was that in the View i was passing for the variable model a Form because of a previous copy and paste.

```
class ProductCommentDelete(CommentOwnerMixin, DeleteView):
    model = ProductComment #not ProductCommentForm
    template_name = 'comments/product-comment-delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

I hope to have been helpful for anyone who will encounter this error.

Comment: How does this answer the question?